# How to determine the date of Starting day of current and last week in python ?

Tags: python, date, datetime

I need to find the date of the starter day of current and last week.

Here, business day of a week starts from SUNDAY. So, for today the date I want is to be "07-16-2017" as "mm--dd--yyyy" format. I can get today's date easily from `datetime.datetime.now().strftime ("%Y-%m-%d")` but from the sysdate I have to pull out the starter day of the week.

I need the starter day's date for last week as well.

There is no default method for week information in datetime. Is there any other method in any package in python to determine the required information ?

Comment: You can probably use the `calendar` module.

Comment: `datetime.today() - timedelta(days=datetime.today().isoweekday() % 7)` will give you the date of the last Sunday (can be easily changed to Monday), but I know it's not exactly what you want.

Comment: You can get Sunday of the week by `dt.strptime(c = dt.now().strftime("%Y-%W-00"),"%Y-%W-%w").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `calendar.firstweekday()` to check what the first day of the week is on that computer (0 is Monday, 6 is Sunday).

1) Let's say that `firstweekday` returned `1` (Sunday). Then you can use

```
date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=date.today().isoweekday() % 7)
```

to compute the date of the last Sunday.

2) Let's say that `firstweekday` returned `0` (Monday).

```
date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=date.today().isoweekday() % 7 - 1)
```

to compute the date of the last Monday.

Hope this gives you some direction.

Comment: calendar.firstweekday() outputs 0 for me

Comment: @W.Jack means, that the beginning of the week is set to Monday.

Comment: If you're unable to figure out how to modify the code above in that case: `date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=time.today().isoweekday() % 7 + 1)` will give you last Monday

Comment: Error:  "AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'today'"

Comment: @W.Jack also, please put a little bit of effort... You should be able to figure it all out yourself by now.

Comment: 'week=datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=datetime.datetime.now().isoweekday() % 7)' worked for me

Comment: And could you please give me any hint for last week's starter day calculation

Comment: @W.Jack sure, in my code we take today's `date` and we subtract a `timedelta`. This way we get a starting day of this week, let's call it `week_start`. Now, you can take `week_start` and substract `timedelta(days=7)` from it to get a date that is a week earlier than that.